# Facebook Like button on Photography site not working right

Tags: button, facebook-like, facebook-iframe

I am new to this.  We have a wedding photography web site. 
http://www.DawnKellyPhotography.com/fbshare/FBalbum/

I have used the Facebook developer page to generate the code to put on the put a Like button on each image's individual page, using the iframe method.

```
<iframe src='//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fdawnkellyphotography.com%2Ffbshare%2FFBalbum%2F%3Fshow%3Dslides%2FNodownLoad.html&amp;send=false&amp;layout=standard&amp;width=450&amp;show_faces=true&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;font&amp;height=80' scrolling='no' frameborder='0' style='border:none; overflow:hidden; width:250px; height:80px;' allowTransparency='true'></iframe>
```

I have also added the meta og tags to the image's html wrapper file.

```
<meta property="og:type"                 content="website"> 
<meta property="og:sitename"             content="Dawn Kelly Photography"> 
<meta property="og:url"                  content="http://www.DawnKellyPhotography.com /fbshare/FBalbum/?show=slides/NodownLoad.html"> 
<meta property="og:image"                content="http://www.DawnKellyPhotography.com/fbshare/FBalbum/slides/NodownLoad.jpg">
<meta property="og:title"                content="Facebook Test Gallery">
```

I was expecting that the Like click would post the og:image and the og:url.  Instead, just a link to the web site's base url is being posted along with the home page's image.  The gallery is generated using JAlbum and a custom skin, and runs on the web site using a custom javascript.  I have access to change any of these as needed.

Thanks in advance.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: OK, the link back to the gallery is working with the code I posted, but no image is being posted on the Facebook wall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing og:image tags from your link you specified in your iframe.

Fix the warnings you have on the [linter tool](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http://dawnkellyphotography.com/fbshare/FBalbum/?show=slides/NodownLoad.html).

```
Inferred Property:  The og:url property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
Inferred Property:  The og:title property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
```

http://graph.facebook.com/10150531249004372

http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/echo?q=http%3A%2F%2Fdawnkellyphotography.com%2Ffbshare%2FFBalbum%2F%3Fshow%3Dslides%2FNodownLoad.html

Comment: I have defined the og:image, og:url, and og:title in the NodownLoad.html file that contains all of the code for the page, displays the image, and where the Like button code is and executed from. The album uses frames. Is FB not processing on the "__/?show=slides/NodownLoad.html" part of the url, so it is not making it back to the correct html file on my site?  Is there a way to compensate for that? The linter appears to be looking at the overall album's default javascript index.html instead of specified NodownLoad.html file.

Comment: Or is Facebook not executing the client-side javascript code, so the "__/?show=slides/NodownLoad.html" part of the url is not followed, resulting in the file that has the tags is not being read?

Comment: The linter does **not** run scripts.  It looks at the raw HTML your server serves to it.  So you need to ensure that your website correctly streams the proper HTML with the proper og: meta tags for the URL requested.

Comment: Thank you.  Now I understand what is happening.  Now I need to figure out the best method of delivering the proper code.  This part of the site runs on javascript and the gallery is generated using either JAlbum or Photoshop, creating more HTML and javascript files.

Comment: Try using url rewrite technology. It should help you figure out how to send the proper content for the url being requested.

Comment: Maybe easier said than done.  Some of the web sites using this script are on Apache, others are on Windows.  Thanks for the suggestion, though. I'll look in to the url rewrite idea.

Comment: Thinking about the url rewrite, would that cause different code to be sent to the Facebook scrapper? The site is still running the same javascript and going through the same code.